# How can I pass the value of the ID on form if the value is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using same form for new and edit, I have written if else conditions for the URL to achieve this.
In this scenario if the record is not created, id of the object wont be present.

how to handle this scenario?

```
if (createRecord == "true"){
    xhr.open("POST", "url", true); 
}else{
    xhr.open("PUT", "url"+<%= @order.id %>, true);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: why not posting to two different actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the action you can write  the `new`, and `edit` logic under a condition like :

```
if params[:id].present? 
  some logic
else 
  another logic goes here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at default scaffold, you will see the 'before_action' you can write a 'before_action' to do Abdullah Fadhel's answer if you don't want to write your code twice.
Also, you should see how default rails action working.